# pytest -k vs pytest -m in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, pytest-markers

I created and used custom markers `orange`, `apple` and `pineapple` as shown below:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
markers =
    orange: Orange marker
    apple: Apple marker
    pineapple: Pineapple marker
```

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.orange
def test1():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.apple
def test2():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.pineapple
def test3():
    assert True
```

Then, I ran `pytest` with `-k orange` and `-m orange` as shown below:

```
pytest -k orange
```

```
pytest -m orange
```

Then, there was the exactly same output as shown below:

```
=================== test session starts ===================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
django: settings: core.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.5.2
collected 3 items / 2 deselected / 1 selected

tests\test_store.py .                                [100%]

============= 1 passed, 2 deselected in 0.09s =============
```

So, what is the difference between `-k` and `-m` in Pytest?

Answer (score 0):

`-k` can run the markers which contain the given string.

`-m` can run the markers which is exactly same as the given string.

So, if you run `pytest` with `-k apple` as shown below:

```
pytest -k apple
```

Then, `apple` and `pineapple` are run as shown below:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.orange # Not run
def test1():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.apple # Run
def test2():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.pineapple # Run
def test3():
    assert True
```

Next, if you run `pytest` with `-m apple` as shown below:

```
pytest -m apple
```

Then, only `apple` is run as shown below:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.orange # Not run
def test1():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.apple # Run
def test2():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.pineapple # Not run
def test3():
    assert True
```